# Carousel Disappears when screen is adjusted or on scroll on mobile devices

Tags: jquery, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries, carousel

I am struggling with trying to fix this issue it looks like it has some errors but thought someone more familiar with this issue might be able to resolve it or at least point me in the right direction.

https://staging-digemaya.kinsta.cloud/online-courses/sleep-deeply-with-sophrology/

```
  <section class="sales-testimonials">
  <div class="st-intro">
    <div class="st-inner">
      {!! $the_intro !!}
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="quotes-wrapper quotes-wrapper-scoped">
    <style scoped="">
  </style>
    <div class="quotes-bg {{ isset($idx) ? 'quotes-bg-' . $idx : '' }}"></div>
    <div class="quotes"
      data-cycle-fx="carousel"
      {{-- data-cycle-carousel-visible=2 --}}
      data-cycle-timeout="{!! $timeout + 3000 !!}"
      data-cycle-slides="> .quote"
      data-cycle-log="false"
      data-cycle-prev=".q-prev{{ isset($idx) ? '-' . $idx : '' }}"
      data-cycle-next=".q-next{{ isset($idx) ? '-' . $idx : '' }}"
      data-cycle-pager=".quotes-pager{{ isset($idx) ? '-' . $idx : '' }}"
    >
      @foreach ($the_quotes as $the_quote)
        <div class="quote q-{{ $loop->iteration }} qid-{!! $the_quote['id'] !!} @if (isset($cls)) {{ $cls }} @endif">
          <div class="d-flex flex-column align-items-center">
            @php
              $fimg = App::get_featured_image_by_ID($the_quote['id'])
            @endphp
            <div class="q-photo align-self-center align-self-xl-auto">
              <img src="{!! $fimg[0] !!}" width="{{ $fimg[1] }}" height="{{ $fimg[2] }}" alt="{{ $the_quote['by'] }}">
            </div>
            <div class="q-content align-self-center align-self-xl-auto">
              {!! $the_quote['quote'] !!}
              <p class="by">{{ $the_quote['by'] }}</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      @endforeach
    </div>
    <div class="q-prev{{ isset($idx) ? '-' . $idx : '' }} d-none d-sm-block">{{ \BladeSvgSage\svg_image('next', 'svg-prev')->sprite() }}<span class="sr-only sr-focusable">{{ __('Previous quote', 'sage') }}</span></div>
    <div class="q-next{{ isset($idx) ? '-' . $idx : '' }} d-none d-sm-block">{{ \BladeSvgSage\svg_image('next', 'svg-next')->sprite() }}<span class="sr-only sr-focusable">{{ __('Next quote', 'sage') }}</span></div>
    <div class="quotes-pager{{ isset($idx) ? '-' . $idx : '' }} text-center"></div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Hi, I can see an error in the console.

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'remove' of undefined
    at Object.onDestroy (jquery.cycle2.carousel.min_905f048c.js:1)
    at HTMLDivElement.i (jquery.min.js:2)
    at HTMLDivElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:2)
    at HTMLDivElement.v.handle (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.trigger (jquery.min.js:2)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Function.each (jquery.min.js:2)
    at s.fn.init.each (jquery.min.js:2)
    at s.fn.init.trigger (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.o.API.trigger (jquery.cycle2_905f048c.js:6)`

Comment: Also the `<div class="quotes"...` HTML element gets hidden. So somewhere in your code you or the plugin might be setting the carousel's display property to "none".

Comment: I will look into the template and see I think they were using bootstrap. I will look for a display none somewhere in the code. Thanks for the help

Comment: Sure! Check the carousel plugin's code.